# Whistling bomb sound

Tags: whistling, sound-design, sound-effects, film

Hey Guys!

First time posting.

i was wondering if anyone has any ideas on creating a whistling bomb sound, like a falling bomb. without sounding too cartoony.

my first thought was to record a Nerf Vortex throwing missile toy thing, which i have recorded, by me blowing in the whistles, they sound ok, but i think i need more to it. may be good for a layer, but sounds a little bit like old style boiling kettle haha

has anyone done it before?

i looked on youtube and found a bunch of fireworks, but i dont think ill be able to get any in australia haha.

cheers
JF

Answer (score 3):

Once you find/design the actual sound you like, having a slow doppler effect (without direction) will give it that falling effect.

Comment: @Andrew - thanks for mentioning that. I meant to mention that but it completely slipped my mind. It's 2am where I'm at and my head is focused on this batch of presets I'm doing for a synth company.

Comment: @Syndicate I always do that, I write something and as I hit "post" I remember something obvious! hehe 

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this effect by automating the pitch of an oscillator downwards over time (the duration of the sound), adding a bit of distortion to add screeching harmonics and then automating reverb to have a longer tail over the duration of the sound.

The reverb on that will vary depending on the perspective. Say if the perspective is of the bomb just leaving the bay of the airplane and getting further away then the tail would get longer over time.

Comment: Interesting! ill give that a try right now! thanks for the quick response

Comment: Another easy way of automating the pitch in Pro Tools is with The Vari-Fi AudioSuite plug in (it sort of a Vinyl Record Start or Stop type Effect). I'd be sure to select some extra space at the end so it doesn't bring the region to 100% pitch bend on the end. It's a selection based plug-in similar to how it'll cut off a reverb tail if you don't select extra space at the end of your region. So it does this over your selection space say from 0-100% from Selection Start to Selection End. You likely won't want your audio to get to 100%.

Comment: @Syndicate @Jamie Great suggestion! I always use Vari-Fi for effects like that - works great for camera flash charging sfx too.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be that guy, but... You could just record yourself whistling. Save a lot of time on automation.